# What causes for not appearing iOS accessibility elements in automation tests?

Tags: ios, swift, automation, accessibility

I have a table view with a custom cell that I set accessibility elements for its components.
All of the accessibility IDs are appearing in the Xcode's Accessibility Inspector, as you see:
[image]

But when it comes down to automation testing, none of the accessibility IDs are visible and don't appear in the XML. It's like this:

[image]

What's the reason for occuring this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Running XCUITest + Appium? Have you made sure the locator strategy is set to “accessibility id”?

More here:
https://appiumpro.com/editions/60-how-to-pick-the-right-locator-strategy